# What is wrong with this specific sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

What is wrong with this sql query:

```
select a.*
from samples_order a
inner join
( 
    select distinct customeremail, min(id) as id
    from samples_order group by customeremail
) as b
    on a.customeremail = b.customeremail 
    and a.id = b.id where order_site="blindsuk" 
    and order_status = "logged" limit 50, 0 
order by id desc
```

Error returned:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order by id desc' at line 8

```
select a.* 
from samples_order a 
   inner join (
      select distinct customeremail, min(id) as id 
      from samples_order 
      group by customeremail 
   ) as b on a.customeremail = b.customeremail and a.id = b.id 
where order_site="blindsuk" 
  and order_status = "logged" 
limit 50, 0 
order by id desc
```

Comment: Check execution precedence of commands/clauses :D like Order by should come in before hand. Where `LIMIT` the last :)

Comment: character literals should be in single quotes. `"blindsuk"` is a column name, `'blindsuk'` is a character literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` clause should come first before `LIMIT`

so,

```
SELECT a.*
FROM samples_order a
     INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT customeremail
        , min(id) AS id
    FROM samples_order
    GROUP BY customeremail
    ) AS b
    ON a.customeremail = b.customeremail
        AND a.id = b.id
WHERE   order_site = "blindsuk"
    AND order_status = "logged" 
ORDER BY id DESC                           -- ORDER BY before LIMIT
LIMIT 50, 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was unaware of that. Will accept the answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: [SQL Query Order of Operations (*click here*)](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-SQL-Query-Order-of-Operations.htm)